# Classes and libraries not being included in Google App Engine web application?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, maven

I'm currently working on a "Google app engine" app using the Eclipse plugin. I've written the first slice of the application but I'm having real trouble ensuring that everything is being included.

My app compiles just fine but when it starts to run it throws:

```
Could not instantiate listener com.mypackage.development.MyClass 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mypackage.development.MyClass
```

Where "MyClass" is a local class that I have written.

It then procedes to throw:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
```

Then:

```
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
```

And so on, presumably as it makes it's way through web.xml. I'm importing the 1.17.1 jersey-core, -servlet, -server, -json using Maven so I can't see why that should occur and, as I say, it all compiles correctly.

It almost seems as if my classes and external libraries aren't being included in the build, is there perhaps something I'm missing here? I've been tearing my hair out over it all morning and i'm really at a loss, I feel like I've tried everything!

I've included my web.xml and my gwt.xml (the latter of which is located inside src/com/mypackage/development) in the hope that it might help shed some light on this issue!

http://www.sendspace.com/file/7peiyx
http://www.sendspace.com/file/vw44yv

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure the Google Eclipse plugin picks up the libraries provided by Maven. Try uploading our app by [running the `mvn appengine:update` goal](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/maven#uploading_your_app_to_production_app_engine) on your project.

NB : the doc tells you to run this command at the root of your ear directory, but if you have a simple default app, it probably has only 1 module, and you should run this command at the project's root directory, where your pom.xml file is located.

Comment: Good shout, I'll give that a go. From what I've read I believe if you have a maven plugin installed then it should still include the maven jars but it's worth a try anyway :). Though it also appears it can't see my local files too since it also fires an exception when referencing MyClass?

Comment: If you can, try posting your full project. If you cannot, try at least to post your pom and the exact file structure.

Comment: Also, at some point Eclipse might have asked you where the Web Application folder is. If you answer "src/main/webapp" the plugin will wipe out any file in there. The right answer is "target/webappname-version", basically the Maven build directory. Check if your "src/main/webapp" folder is empty.